# Wicked_PDF not rendering bootstrap 4 styles

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

Following my previous wicked_pdf question, now that I am rendering the correct template I cannot get the pdf to render the bootstrap styling of the application.

I am using bootstrap 4, ruby '2.4.2' and gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'

app/controllers/proposals_controller.rb

```
def show
    @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
    @custom_content = @proposal.custom_contents
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "some_name",
               template: "proposals/show.pdf.erb",
               layout: "pdf.html",
               margin: { top: 35, bottom: 35 }
      end
    end
  end
```

app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PDF</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" -%>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container d-flex justify-content-center'>
  test 2
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
app/views/proposals/show.pdf.erb

<div class="row full-page justify-content-center" id="cover">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row p-0">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-end ">
        <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag '1209232_1920-1.jpg' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-1 d-flex align-items-end text-justify">
      <div class="col-12 text-justify cover-background">
        <div class="row pt-1">
          <h2 class="text-white text-justify">Proposal For <br> Maintenance</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-0">
          <div class="col-6">
            <h5 class="text-white text-justify">Prepared For: <%= @proposal.contact.name %></h5>
            <h6></h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <h5 class="text-white text-justify">Prepared By: <%= @proposal.user.name %></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
// $navbar-default-bg: #312312;
// $light-orange: #ff8c00;
// $navbar-default-color: $light-orange;
$brand-color: #30AADD;

@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "sticky-footer";
@import "announcements";
@import "summernote-bs4";
@import "summernote-custom-theme.min";
@import "material_icons";


// Proposal Cover
.full-page {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.cover-image{
  background-image: url('https://heliportstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/new-york-1209232_1920-1.jpg');
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.cover-background {
  background: $brand-color;
}

plus alot of custom styling
```

I have looked through alot of cases of this but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your head of the `pdf.html.erb`, you need to reference the bootstrap css file.

```
<head>
  <title>PDF</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" -%>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>
</head>
```

Add the bootstrap.css file to your assets/stylesheets.

Comment: does that mean I have to create a bootstrap.scss file?

Comment: Should already be in your assets folder. Unless you're using a gem for bootstrap.

Comment: drum roll please... yes I am... but... I did try <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" %> but got nothing... anythoughts?

Comment: have you added  *= require bootstrap to your application.css? Try adding the bootstrap.css (download from site) file to your assets/stylesheets.

Comment: my application scss @import "bootstrap"; isn't enough? i didnt now I could *= require

Comment: what gem is it?

Comment: gem 'bootstrap'

Comment: I would give my updated answer a go. I know in the past when just trying to link in with the application.scss doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: DollarChills, i can't get bootstrap into either of the apps( test and actual) for me.... I am moving to prawn